# What is the best way to keep track of class instances in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, class-design

I am making an app that uses a class I will call Player the number of Player instances can go up to 10 and down to 2. I am wondering what is the best way to keep track of all of these instances? For now I am just making an array in my view controller that I can add to and remove from as necessary, but is there a better way? I was wondering if there is such a thing as class variables as there are class methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest using an NSSet instead of an NSArray, unless the order they are created is required.

Comment: I discovered that what i needed to do was create another object to manage my child objects. ie Players keeps track of each player instance. I'm new to this OOP world but I think Im figuring things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that what i needed to do was create another object to manage my child objects. ie Players keeps track of each player instance. I'm new to this OOP world but I think Im figuring things out.

Comment: That would be called a controller in OOP design terms. You might want to search on MVC or the Model-View-Controller design pattern for another aha-moment.

Answer (score 0):

In objective-C the static methods are called as class methods. They all will be called by the class name.

eg:

```
+(void)classMethod
{

}

[Class classMethod];
```

Comment: I understand class methods, but is there a way to make a Class Property, perhaps an array that i can add all the instances to, so I could have Player.list that is a list of all player instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize properties for your class variables and then use them.